# How can I replace value with a different value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I already change the NULL to a different value. My problem now is how can I change if there is value? Can somebody help me with my problem?

```
ID  Name
1   John
2   
3   Doe
```

I want this to happen when I display it to my page...

```
ID  Name
1   Secret
2   NULL
3   Secret
```

This is my query

```
SELECT id AS ID, COALESCE(first_name, 'NULL') AS Name FROM tbl_user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
select id, case when first_name is null then 'NULL' else 'Secret' end as Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE WHEN name IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE 'Secret' END Name
FROM mytable
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0dd46d0bdfdfc3aac547fe7727012d90)** with your sample data returns:

```
id | Name  
-: | :-----
 1 | Secret
 2 | NULL  
 3 | Secret
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer. using `CASE` and `IFNULL`

```
SELECT id AS ID
   , CASE WHEN IFNULL(first_name, '') = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE first_name END AS Name 
FROM tbl_user
```